# Android Youtube V3 Simple API 403 Error: accessNotConfigured

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

While trying to grab a simple json feed of a playlist I encountered this error.

I didn't want to include the Youtube library for such a small snippet, so I opted to grab the json manually using:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=<API_KEY>&playlistId=<PLAYLIST_ID>`

But I kept receiving:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

- I had enabled the API via the console
- I had gotten the key using both my debug.keystore and my release.keystore
- The package name was correct, as were the SHA1's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

Use the **Key for browser applications** instead of the Android key. And don't forget to use **https**

Leave the referrers field blank.

Hopefully this saves someone else some time - it would have saved me a bit!